# vuex state not updating UI on change

Tags: vuex, vuejs3

I am in the process of converting a vue2 to vue3 project and noticed my UI isn't updating when objects from my vuex store are updating. Here is how I create my store:

store/index.js

```js
import {mutations} from './mutations';
import {createStore} from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state() {
    return {
       ...
    }
   },
   mutations
});
```

mutations.js

```js
export const mutations = {
  narrative(state, v) {
    state.narrative = v;
  }
};
```

app.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import store from './store/index';

const app = createApp({
  mixins: [
    require('./mixins/base')
  ]
}).use(store)
```

So when I mutate one of the vuex objects, I write to the console log immediately and see the data has changed

```js
        let narrative = _.find(this.$store.state.narratives, ['id', this.selectedNarrativeId]);
        if (narrative) {
          console.log(narrative.id); // PRINTS CORRECT UPDATED ID
          this.$store.commit('narrative', narrative);
          console.log(this.$store.state.narrative.id); // PRINTS CORRECT UPDATED ID
        }
```

But the UI does not change. However, if I used a computed property, the UI updates immediately. What am I doing wrong with the vuex store?

```js
computed: {
    currentNarrative() {
        let narrative = _.find(this.$store.state.narratives, ['id', this.selectedNarrativeId]);
        if (narrative) {
          return narrative;
        }
        return {};
      },
}
```

Versions

- vue 3.2.33
- vuex 4.0.2

Comment: What do you see in your Vue devtools? Is it updated there?

Comment: No it isn't. It shows it as empty in the devtools

Comment: But other vuex state objects are populated. The ones that are populated on load. But after load, it's like it's not tracking changes. (according to the dev tools)

Comment: Btw, are you sure that a `commit` is fine here? Shouldn't it be an action? And also, why do you use `require` for `mixins/base` rather than `import`?

Comment: I added my mutation to the store in the OP. I use `commit` throughout the app like this in vue2 and it worked just fine. The state was always updated immediately. And it is printing the proper data to the console after the "commit" right now, just not changing in the UI. The `require` has been there for years and worked fine in vue2, so I never messed with it.

Comment: `commit` is fine if you only have `sync` operations. `actions` need to be used if you have anything `async` in your code (otherwise, race-condition or strange errors). In modern front-end (and also backend actually), we use modern `import` for a lot of reasons (one of them being performance). So even if it works like that, you should probably update it towards `import`.

Comment: OK updated. Also I will note I just reboot my machine and all of a sudden everything is working as expected. It's obnoxious but it's fixed. Going to delete this post shortly but wanted to let you know and thanks for helping.

Comment: There is no real benefit into deleting a post. So I recommend leaving it overall. Glad that it works now. Did you made any `import` + `action` updated or is it working out of the blue for some reason?

Comment: @kissu I did not change to `action` in these instances but did update to an `import`. That didn't appear to impact anything. One of those annoying mysteries. Any suggested reading on better npm practices? I'm a novice with npm config overall and could use a crash course so I'm better aware in the future. Thanks!

Comment: You don't really need to take a crash course on NPM or alike, just read the official documentation of Vue and it's ecosystem. The examples are well done and usually pretty precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the `require` by an `import` + rebooting the machine fixed the issue, maybe some broken was still running on the server.